# Solidity project error with my deploy.js script

Tags: web3js, javascript, solidity-0.8.x

I cannot get this to work:

```
npx hardhat run scripts/deploy.js --network localhost
```

The deploy script returns:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'JsonRpcProvider')
```

This is my deploy script:

```
const hre = require("hardhat");
async function main(){
    const ChatApp = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory("ChatApp");
    const chatApp = await ChatApp.deploy();
    await chatApp.deployed();
    console.log(` Contract Address: ${ChatApp.address}`);

main().catch((error) => {
    console error(error);
    process.exitCode = 1;
});
```

Can someone help me out, please?

Comment: Can you provide more details? The script is missing a closing `}`. It could be a wrong dependency, or some problem with the scripts.

Comment: Can you include the rest of the deploy script?  As Ismael mentioned you are missing a closing bracket but also I don't see where you are using/trying to use `JsonRpcProvider`.